# Load BSON Model in Three.js?

Tags: json, three.js, bson

Actually Three.js has `JSONLoader` to load JSON models.
Is it possible to convert JSON 3D model to BSON and load it using Three.js? Because I need to load huge JSON model.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a suggestion for BSON but you can take a look at the source in three.js\utils\converters\msgpack and http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_msgpack and you can read more about the format here: http://msgpack.org/

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. Actually I want to load huge JSON model. I used WebWorker also but the browser unable to render the model. Please suggest.

Comment: But how Three.js' JSONLoader() recognize it?

Comment: If you look at the example that I posted, `THREE.ObjectLoader()` will recognize it.

Comment: Ok thank you. But how can I convert my JSON to msg format? Is there any Python like program which does this?

Comment: yes, also in my post. (in three.js\utils\converters\msgpack)

Comment: I tried but the materials array of objects are not available as in the parent format. So I am getting collapsed model.

Comment: sorry it was not clear from your question how many materials you have. depending on the number of materials you have you might try splitting it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am having more than 100 materials.

Comment: then splitting is not an option.

Comment: Ok. Please let me know. Is it possible to load 160 mb of JSON file which has vertices, faces and morphTargets? What is the THREE.JSONLoader()?